# using item property inside an event procedure

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a quick question. How can i check an item's properties within an event procedure? Here is a snippet of what I'm trying to do:

```
Private Sub application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim myolitem As Object
Set myolitem = Item
    If myolitem.Class = olMail Then
        If myolitem.UnRead Then
            UserForm2.Show vbModal
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You code looks good, I don't see anything strange there.

Hope you will find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) article helpful.

Comment: I get an error message saying that I can't access item properties (the unread property) within this event. When i try to replace it with a call to another sub it doesn't recognize the item anymore. I have tried to go around that by declaring the item via the "withevent" but that won't work either because i can't use that for objects apparently. I've read parts of that article and can't seem to find a solution when it should be something basic. I'm going mad over here. Thank you for the feedback though

Answer (score 0):

Some events (e.g. `AfterWrite`, `ItemLoad`) only allow a limited number of properties to be accessed. In your particular case, these are `Class` and `MessageClass` - see [ApplicationEvents_11_Event.ItemLoad event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.applicationevents_11_event.itemload.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).
I don't know if `MAPIOBJECT` is accessible in `ItemLoad` (I know for sure it is accessible in the `AfterWrite` event), you can (in theory) access the properties using Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) (I am its author).